# Is disabling webSecurity on the Electron window the only way to display local images?

Tags: webpack, electron

I want my Electron app to display local images:

```html
<!-- file.path has value of C:/Users/name/Desktop/1.png -->
<img :src="file.path">
```

but when I use an image tag I get this error:

`Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/name/Desktop/1.png`

### Question:

As I understand it, in order to be able to load local images I have to turn off webSecurity by adding `webPreferences: { webSecurity: false }`

- Is that safe to do? Disabling something called `webSecurity` on the main window doesn't sound safe
- Is that really the only way an electron app can display user's local images located outside the app's directory

---

P.S. it's an Electron-Vue project. It uses webpack.

Comment: Are you using Webpack? There are loads of `Not allowed` issues related to Webpack...

Comment: @Tim yes it uses webpack. Not sure why there's almost no info about it on the internet, surely people have tried displaying local images in their electron apps before.

Comment: Google your error + electron + webpack and you'll see dozens of issues with possible solutions

Comment: when you call `loadUrl` after opening your browser window, are you loading a local file path or `localhost`?

Comment: @Tim the `loadUrl` function calls this constant: **const winURL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
  ? `http://localhost:9080`
  : `file://${__dirname}/index.html`**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Electron will not load `file://` urls while it is running a page from a non-file URL (http://localhost:9080 in your case).

This means you only need to disable `webSecurity` when you're in development mode and running from the Webpack development server.

In production you can leave `webSecurity` enabled as you're loading from a file: `file://${__dirname}/index.html`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That clarifies it. Though how do I make sure I have `webSecurity` disabled only in the dev mode? I just added this line `webPreferences: { webSecurity: false }` in the `mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ })` in my index.js file

Comment: `webPreferences: { webSecurity: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development' }`

Comment: Ah, so that line `webSecurity: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development'` has value of **false** in the dev mode, and it equals **true** in production, awesome, thank you very much for your help!